# Disable all dates except the last date of each month in Angular Matrial Calendar component

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, calendar

There is any way to disable all dates except the last day of each month using Angular Material. I want that the user select only this specific date (last date of each month). it is possible?
There is a [matDatepickerFilter] property but for a specific list of dates.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matDatePickerFilter` is not for a list of dates, it is for a function to determine if a particular date should be selectable or not.

You can simply define a function and pass it as the `matDatepickerFilter`:

```js
  isLastDayOfMonth(date: Date | null): boolean {
    date = date ?? new Date();
    const dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
    const lastDayOfMonth = getLastDayOfMonth(date);

    return dayOfMonth === lastDayOfMonth;
  };
```

```html
<input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="isLastDayOfMonth" />
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73719669?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.